# Password management web parts?

Tags: web-part, user-accounts, password

Does anyone of you know some webpart providers. I am desperately looking for a SharePoint webpart which can do following.

- change password
- lost password recovery (e-mail)
- change password reminder (e-mail)

At the moment I have just found following providers which met the specs

1. http://www.envisionit.com/Products/Pages/ExtranetModuleforSharePoint.aspx
2. http://ssc.amexus.com/Prod/bamboo/Seiten/ITProductivityPack.aspx
3. http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint-password-reset-webpart.aspx
4. http://www.boostsolutions.com/password-change-expiration.html

Comment: don't understand why the post has been closed...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Bamboo Solutions [Password Managmenet Cycle For SharePoint](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/06/complete-user-account-management-process.aspx)

Comment: Client of mine is using this one. Heard only good things so far

Answer (score 2):

There's a free web part for changing AD passwords on CodePlex: [ChangePassword.codeplex.com](http://changepassword.codeplex.com/). I've used the 2003 version in our MOSS 2007 portal w/o too much issue, looks like this project has updated it to the 2007 APIs.

It doesn't look like it does email notifications, but users are shown the days remaining until they need to change their password, and you can't beat the price ;)

John

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory Tools For SharePoint is a low cost option that I built.  It doesn't do emailing, but I suppose it could!  I wouldn't be opposed to adding that functionality if it was really desired.

Feel free to drop me a line and let me know if that's something I should code in.

http://dis.mantle.me